# Asterisk SIP peers falling down

Tags: asterisk

the issue with Asterisk 13.7.2 happened about a month ago.
For unknown reasons periodically (2-5 days) all SIPs falling down and cant connect again. Restart Asterisk service doesnt help at all. Only kill Asterisk process or reboot.
All peers are static, so realtime we not using, but using AMI.
Maybe anyone had this problem and know how to solve it?

Comment: Can you please point me, where is programing question here?

Comment: Do you have any logs? Check logs for a hint or paste it here.

Comment: I've also noticed this problem recently.

Comment: what is your server load and asterisk using CPU at that moment. You can use top command. Also you can attach asterisk with GDB and paste here bt and btfull logs.

Comment: It looks like the problem has been solved by itself and I do not know why this happened and finished =) What is realy strange in logs all was good, moreover asterisk continuing to answer the calls (ofcourse without operators) on flow lines without sip registration. But in the reality Asterisk just kick off all sip peers and keep them somewhere in it memory. Cpu and memory load on the server was OK. Maybe the issue was with integrating new ERP, but still nothing in work with Asterisk AMI has been changed in new ERP. It is just strange bug.